# Convert Json to Java Object

Tags: java, json, gson

Here is my Json.  I'm trying to convert it into a java class.  So that I'll be able to parse this json using gson library.  Please help me in writing java class equivalent to json below.

```
{
    "A" :   "One",      
    "B" :   "Two"
}
```

Here is what I've tried.  I wrote a class with this variable and try to parse this class using gson.

```
public Map<String,String> listOfAlphabets = new HashMap<>();
```

Hope my question is clear.  Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a JSON string to `Map` like this:

```
// instantiate Gson instance
Gson gson = new Gson();

// create a Map type
Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();

// jsonString is your JSON string
Map<String,String> alphabetssMap = gson.fromJson(jsonString, mapType);
```

[TypeToken Javadoc](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use automapping in such case, because you can't have dynamic number of fields in a Java Class. It's better to reformat your Json (if it's possible) for using internal Map in Java Class.